# I cant hide python exe file console

Tags: python, cmd, console, window, hide

I wrote a script , this script modify some files on system.
I used [**this lib**](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) with `no console` option but when i run script some terminals show up for 1 second and then they will hide.

I used `Os.system()` in my code.

What should i do to run the script completely silent?

Comment: `no console` option is just meant for the exe itself, but not for os.system.

Answer (score 0):

If you name your files with the ".pyw" extension, then windows will execute them with the pythonw.exe interpreter. This will not open the cmd console for running your script.

Comment: But what about when i compile it to exe?